# How to change all display status using Inspect element tool?

Tags: html, css, web-inspector, inspector

I am aiming to open all collapsible items on a certain website that doesn't belong to me.
The website is built in a way that only one collapsible item can be opened at a time, while I would like to open all items at once:
[Webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG0bK.png)

While inspecting the element I noticed that once an item is clicked its status changes from `"display: none;"` to `"display: block;"`
I can successfully manually change all items from  `"display: none;"` to `"display: block;"`
However, I would like to find an easier way to do so since the webpage contains more than 200 items. Any suggestions on how I might be able to do so?

Here is what the code looks like in one out of 200 similar items-

```
<div class="meaning" data-font-size="17" data-font-size-type="px" data-line-height="24.2857px" style="display: none;">לפחות</div>
```

Comment: You have to use selector and some library to select them. Can you post the relevant part of the code (describing for example one item).

Comment: Sure, thanks for the very quick response mate. here is the relevant part of the code:  <div class="meaning" data-font-size="17" data-font-size-type="px" data-line-height="24.2857px" style="display: none;">לפחות</div>

Comment: Umm.. you should edit it into the question. Try to format your question so that it is easy to read.

Comment: Does the site have jQuery? In inspect console if you type "$" and enter what it gives back?

Comment: It returns: ƒ (e, t) { return new st.fn.init(e, t, X) }

Comment: Does this work? $(".meaning").show()

Comment: Do you care to explain how that worked?

Comment: I explained it in my answer (you should accept it). Please ask there in the comments if you want more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site has jQuery (try "$" in the console) you can find all the `class="meaning"` elements with `$(".meaning")` and then show() them. Like this:

```
$(".meaning").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the site has jquery you can use

```
$(".meaning").css("display", "block");
$(".meaning").css("display", "none");
```